# searching for right ip address in an array of strings - java android

Tags: java, android, loops

I'm new to android java programming. I'm trying to rewrite an app.

i had an editText contaning ip prefixes delimited by ",". e.g. "10.15,10.31,10.42"

```
private void MDConnect() {
String str = getIpAddress();
String [] arrayOfString = editText.getText().toString().split(",");
j = 0

while ( j < arrayOfString.length) {
if (str.substring(0,arrayOfString[j].length()).equals(arrayOfString[j])){
addMessage("Success! Your IP address is " + str);
}else{
j++;}
}
addMessage("Retrying")
// this is where the process will start over. disconnect and then connect to get a fresh new ip address
}
```

my goal is to connect->getIpAdd->check if it matches the ones on the list->if yes, add success message; if no, disconnect and connect again.

Hope someone could help me. Please. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:the code is just checking the first string in the array. it's not looping or moving to the next string. How could i loop an if-statement and do the process i have said in my post?

Comment: What is your question? Is there a problem with the code you provided?

Comment: oh i'm sorry. yes. the code is just checking the first string in the array. it's not looping or moving to the next string. How could i loop an if-statement and do the process i have said in my post. Thanks.

Comment: The following are **not** ip addresses `"10.15,10.31,10.42"`

Comment: @alfasin he said **ip prefixes** in the post

Comment: @alfasin yes. their just IP address prefixes so i trimmed my IP address to match with the prefixes. just like in the code.

Comment: @NoobMode OK, can you add that to your question and also look at the code snippet again? It's missing at least 2 closing braces and I suspect that might be causing the problem.

Comment: first of all, you only increment counter in "else" path. in case of success you have an infinite loop

Comment: @vesan sorry for that. i've edited my code adding }. what do you think is the other reason causing the problem?

Comment: @nouseforname can you write the proper code for me? thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very sloppy and is missing semi-colons and closing brackets. And your loop can be simplified a lot, although your method CAN work, you are making it much harder than it should be. try this code:

```
    String str = getIpAddress();
    String [] arrayOfString = editText.getText().toString().split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfString.length; i++) {
        if (str.substring(0,arrayOfString[i].length()).equals(arrayOfString[i])) {
            addMessage("Success! Your IP address is " + str);
            break;
        } else {
           //not found
           addMessage("Retrying")
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks i'll try this one. i've also tried the for-loop statement but got no luck. similar to this. maybe there's something wrong in my code.

Comment: The line str.substring(0,arrayOfString[i].length()).equals(arrayOfString[i]) still can be simplified by "str.split('.')[i].equals(arrayOfString[i]). Rest is like i also would do it

Comment: Also, it helps naming your variables better: `String ipAddress = getIpAddress()` and `String[] ipPrefixes = ...`

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys.

Comment: @nouseforname Does that code split my IP address as "10" only? i'll be matching it with "10.31".

Comment: @NoobMode if this answer corrected your problem, please click the check to the left of the answer to accept it. Have a nice night!

Answer (score 0):

Move the `addMessage("Retrying")` and disconnect logic outside of the loop, so that it is not executed until it has tried and failed to match on all of the IPs in the array:

```
private void MDConnect() {
    String ip = getIpAddress();
    String[] prefixes = editText.getText().toString().split(",");
    for (String prefix : prefixes) {
        if (ip.startsWith(prefix)) {
            addMessage("Success! Your IP address is " + ip);
            return;
        }
    }
    addMessage("Retrying");
    ...
}
```